# Is SQL Server 2012 express faster than SQL Server 2005 Express?

Tags: sql-server-2005-express, sql-server-2012-express

Recently, I upgraded my development computer to Windows 8 and now, I am having hard time installing SQL Server 2005 express on my development machine. My ASP.NET MVC Website project is based on SQL Server 2005 Express. (Entity Framework CodeFirst 5.0)

Now, I am thinking, maybe upgrading my website dependency to SQL Server 2012 Express can be a good idea. But, I read in some sites that, SQL Server 2012 is slower than SQL Server 2008, and SQL Server 2008 is slower than SQL Server 2005. My database tables are very simple, does not require new features of SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2012.

I am little confused, can you please give me any suggestion about it ? I mean, is it true that SQL Server 2012 express is slower than SQL Server 2005 express ? If so, then, I will try to stick to SQL Server 2005 express as I really do not need the extra features of SQL 2012.

Comment: I would suggest to set performance benchmark and load of data, before testing on performance. In addition, hardware specification and load of server also plays biggest role in this assessment.

Comment: The biggest limitation you get from using 2005 is that your databases are limited to 4GB instead of 10GB.

Comment: Hi @djangofan, thank you for your comment. Actually, I may not need more than 4GB near future. My first priority concern is speed of query execution. Even if the speed of query execution of SQL Express 2012 is not worse than SQL Express 2005, I will be happy to upgrade.

Comment: I would imagine that the speed is not very different since, in all cases, SQL Express only uses 1 processor.   Speed differences probably depend on table sizes, indexes, hard drive speed, etc.